# Windows Azure: how to measure the execution time of a code

Tags: windows, azure, execution

I wanted to measure the execution time of my code running on windows azure cloud across multiple instances. Can anyone tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the diagnostics logging and put the intrumentation/logging from the ap into an Azure Table.  Then download into Excel or whatever for analysis.  You can also capture perfmon data to do correlation (e.g. CPU vs workingset).

Answer (score 0):

You have to compute this manually.

Just in case you are requesting this to derive billing information, remember that in Windows Azure, you are charged by reserved instance not necesarily "running".

If your application is "suspended" you still pay. If your code application is running, but "idling" (like 99% CPU free), you still pay the same.

Comment: @Pace: is there no specific tool to measure the execution time. I have coded 2 codes. So, I wanted to know which code will have better execution time which in turn gives better performance.